# Is there a more efficient way to apply this custom function to the entire dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, dataset

I have a dataset that looks like this with IP addresses (for security's sake, these are all made up):

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.0.200.0 | 160.60.30.0 | NaN |
| NaN | 101.60.10.0 | 10.0.0.1 |

I want to apply a function that would take these IP addresses (where they exist) and essentially return a sliced version of them by removing the fourth octet so it should look like this:

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.0.200 | 160.60.30 | NaN |
| NaN | 101.60.10 | 10.0.0 |

I have written the below code that does the job but it is very slow since it uses recursion and I want to be able to do this faster.

```
def sliceip(row):
 row = str(row)
 return row.rsplit(".",1)[0]

def applysliceip(rowx):
 for i, item in enumerate(rowx):
     rowx[i] = sliceip(item)
 return rowx


# And I apply this to the entire dataframe as such:

split_IPs = IPs.apply(lambda row: applysliceip(row))
```

**So my Question is there a more pythonic and faster way to accomplish the above and return the same output without having to use so much memory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match and replace instead of using a custom function.

```
IPs.replace(r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+", r"\1", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, which uses [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and `regex` to replace the last `.` and `digits` by empty string:

```
import re

df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'\.\d+$', '', x))
```

Output:

```
           0          1       2
0  100.0.200  160.60.30     NaN
1        NaN  101.60.10  10.0.0
```

---

A faster solution, based on `numpy`:

```
import re

v = np.vectorize(lambda x: re.sub(r'\.\d+$', '', x))
pd.DataFrame(np.where(pd.notnull(df), v(df), df))
```

Comment: Thank you , the vectors are a great idea.